# Existence of matrices with non-zero principal minors

Tags: matrices, determinant

The problem sounds very simple but I have yet to come to an answer.
Prove or disprove:

> For all $n$ there exists a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $\det(A) = 0$ such that all first minors $M_{i,j} \neq 0$.

Trivial example for $n=2$:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Could you please explain what are minors $M_{ì,j}$? It is a while I passed this course...

Comment: $M_{i,j}$ is referring to the determinant of A' = {A with row i and column j removed}.

Comment: By 'first', do you mean $i=1$, $j=1$, or either?

Comment: What you need to find is $n$ linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that any collection of $n-1$ of them is linearly independent. These will be the columns of your matrix. I am not certain that is sufficient, but it is necessary.

Comment: @Semiclassical, first minors is referring to their order, i.e. only one row and colum is removed

Answer (score -1):

Hint: assume the $n$ variable matrix looks the same (all ones), and compute it's determinant by the cofactor of minors method. We know what the determinant of any possible 2 by 2 minor is. What does this tell us?

Comment: These determinants $M_{i,j}$ are 0 for the cases n > 2